# How to turn off parse-numbers for a single entry in a \numlist command?

Tags: siunitx

I am using `\numlist` from the `siunitx` package to type a long list of numbers.

The minimal code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%
\begin{document}
%
\numlist{1e3;1.0;1.}
%
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

The first and second entry in the list are printed fine. However, I would like to turn off `parse-numbers` for the third entry, i.e., print it as `1.` rather than `1.0`, so that the output would be as

[image]

I have tried to protect the third entry by placing braces like this `\numlist{1e3;1.0;{1.}}` and even double braces, but neither did work (the double braces even threw an error of invalid token).

Is it possible to turn off `parse-numbers` or change the format of a **single entry** in `\numlist`?

Comment: What's the real reason for this? If the final period is punctuation, it should go outside of `\numlist`.

Comment: @ergeg It is not a punctuation. I am writing some notes for students about significant figures for which I am trying to explain that for example a list of all these numbers have four significant figures 100.0, 1.000, 1.000 x10^10, 1000., etc. As you can see, the last number with 3 trailing zeros should be followed by a point to have a 4 significant figures. Typing it as it is  in the `\numlist` entries renders it parsed to 1000.0 format which totally changes its significant figures into 5. Otherwise dropping the point would change it to 1000 which only has 1 significant figure.

Comment: I’m not sure that 1000 is considered to have just one significant figure, unless you write it as `1\times10^3`

Comment: @egreg Both `1000` and `1\times10^3` have one significant figure. "Trailing zeros in a whole number with no decimal point are not significant." This is a basic rule for counting significant figures.

Comment: I see “In most contexts it is understood that trailing zeros are only shown if they are significant”

Comment: I think that if you make a feature request to the maintainer of `siunitx`, explaining the convention and pointing to authoritative sources using it, he will take it into account.

Comment: I agree with you, perhaps in many context other than strict significant figures rules (to which I have to commit for now in my notes) the trailing zeros may be treated as significant. I will consider asking @Joseph Wright for this feature. Perhaps allowing individual brace protected entries in `\numlist` to skip being parsed, if possible, will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a feature request for `siunitx` is in order, to have an option such as `keep-trailing-decimal-marker` for such a case.

In the meantime, here's a workaround, not as flexible as `siunitx`, though.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\numsd}{m}
 {
  \hesham_num_sd:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\numlistsd}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_tl \l_tmpa_tl { \hesham_num_sd:n {##1} }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_tmpb_tl
   { \nobreakspace and\nobreakspace }% between two
   {,~ }% between more than two
   {\nobreakspace and\nobreakspace }% between last two
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \hesham_num_sd:n
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { . } { \str_range:nnn { #1 } { -1 } { -1 } }
   {
    \exp_args:Ne \num { \str_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { -2 } }.
   }
   {
    \num { #1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\numlistsd{1e3;1.0;1.}

\numsd{10000.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like all siunitx commands you can add options to them directly in square brackets.

In your case, the command should look like:

```
\numlist[parse-numbers=false]{1;1.0;1.}
```

Comment: Well that will not solve the problem if I have another number like 1e3 which I would like to be parsed.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. Sorry for the inconvenience!